# roll data.table with rollends

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having trouble getting `roll=-Inf` to work when defining `rollends=FALSE`.  When `rollends` is not set or set to `TRUE`, I see the expected result.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
library(data.table)

dt1 = data.table(Date=seq(from=as.Date("2013-01-03"),
                          to=as.Date("2013-06-27"), by="1 week"),
                 key="Date")[, ind:=.I]
dt2 = data.table(Date=seq(from=as.Date("2013-01-01"),
                          to=as.Date("2013-06-30"), by="1 day"),
                 key="Date")
```

I would expect to see `2013-01-05` and `2013-06-26` populated in the output below.

```
dt1[dt2, roll=-Inf, rollends=FALSE]
           Date ind
  1: 2013-01-01  NA
  2: 2013-01-02  NA
  3: 2013-01-03   1
  4: 2013-01-04   2
  5: 2013-01-05  NA
 ---               
177: 2013-06-26  NA
178: 2013-06-27  26
179: 2013-06-28  NA
180: 2013-06-29  NA
181: 2013-06-30  NA
```

This is working as expected, the `ind` data is rolled forward but not outside of the endpoints defined in the `dt1` `data.table`.

```
dt1[dt2, roll=-Inf]
           Date ind
  1: 2013-01-01   1
  2: 2013-01-02   1
  3: 2013-01-03   1
  4: 2013-01-04   2
  5: 2013-01-05   2
 ---               
177: 2013-06-26  26
178: 2013-06-27  26
179: 2013-06-28  NA
180: 2013-06-29  NA
181: 2013-06-30  NA
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right. This looks like a bug.

**UPDATE** : Now fixed in [v1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240) (commit 980). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> `X[Y,roll=-Inf,rollends=FALSE]` didn't roll the middle correctly if `Y` was keyed. It was ok if `Y` was unkeyed or `rollends` left as the default [`c(TRUE,FALSE)` when `roll<0`]. Thanks to user338714 for reporting. Tests added.

Thanks for the great question!

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks for the responsiveness.